# System is Slow when using booleans

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, performance

Just started doing some of Blender Tutorials and was wondering why things are slowing down. Not things like pan and orbit, they're fine . But moving booleans around is painfully slow. Like when you try to reposition them to change the effect. This is not a complex model. I have a  newer Dell laptop Core i9-10980 2.4 GHz Nvidia Gforce RTX 2070 Super and 32 gb of ram. I thought this would be more than sufficient to handle the software. I was on the phone with Dell and they checked everything out and there was no difference running Blender afterward. Is there something in the preferences that I need to set?

Comment: Two options: learn not to rely on booleans and use modeling instead. Or change the solver on the boolean modifier from "exact" to "fast" (read: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.91/Modeling). The exact solver uses a lot more resources. Seriously consider going with the first option. Boolean operations are a lazy shortcut, that usually results in problematic topology.

Comment: Care to upload the file in question? Maybe it is more complex than it seems?

Comment: I'm not sure where to upload the file. As soon as I figure that out I'll post it. Also, I'll be reviewing the wiki. Thanks

Comment: @marchmoran upload here: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1):

Using the Fast modifier instead of Exact (default).

[image]